# how to post object in object with angular 6

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular6

I need to post data like this to my Api created with spring boot

```
workflow : any = {
    name : "CMD1",
    items : [ {
      name : "work1",
      content : null
    }, {
      name : "work2",
      content : null
    } ]
  }
```

I create model of this workflow in angular

```
  constructor(
    public id:string,
    public name:string,
    public items: Items[]
  ){}
  export class Items (
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public content: string
  ){} )
```

when i have post this this data from postman , this Api take the data and saved , and when i declare workflow like top declared data correctly saved.
My problem is when i send data from template , i can't create type of data like this json

```
workflow : any = {
    name : "CMD1",
    items : [ {
      name : "work1",
      content : null
    }, {
      name : "work2",
      content : null
    } ]
  }
```

how can i send object in another angular object, and for send data which form method I use it ???
thanks to help me ...

Comment: How are you getting data to your form and submitting it? Please update with a working demo or a snippet of code reflecting your form.

Comment: this my problem how i can create this submitting in html and typescript , i success add only name saved  with template , but i can't load items correctly .

Answer (score 0):

you can using lodash to create object like that